# Implementing gallery with images from the web

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I am trying to implement a gallery with images loaded from the web as per [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/) tutorial.
But i am having a null pointer error.The image urls are successfully fetched from the database.
Heres my main class

```
List<String> photos;

Gallery gallery;
ImageView image;

private static final String url_photos = "http://xxxxxxxxx/get_photos.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_PHOTO = "name";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "photos";

private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "advert_description";
private static final String KEY_ID = "advert_id";
private static final String KEY_RATE = "advert_rate";
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "advert_location";
private static final String KEY_FUEL = "advert_fuel";
private static final String KEY_ENGINE = "advert_engine";
private static final String KEY_MODEL = "advert_model";
private static final String KEY_MAKE = "advert_make";
private static final String KEY_TRANSMISSION = "advert_transmission";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cardetails,
            container, false);
    photos = new ArrayList<>();

    make = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_make);
    model = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_model);
    transmission = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_transmission);
    engine = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_engine);
    seating = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_seating);
    location = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_location);
    rates = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_rates);
    description = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_description);
    fuel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardetails_textView_fuel);

    gallery = (Gallery) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_gallery_photos);
    image = (ImageView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.cardetails_imageView_image);

    new GetImages().execute();

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        advert_description = bundle.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
        advert_price = bundle.getString(KEY_RATE);
        advert_location = bundle.getString(KEY_LOCATION);
        advert_id = bundle.getInt(KEY_ID);
        advert_transmission = bundle.getString(KEY_TRANSMISSION);
        advert_fuel = bundle.getString(KEY_FUEL);
        advert_engine = bundle.getString(KEY_ENGINE);
        advert_model = bundle.getString(KEY_MODEL);
        advert_make = bundle.getString(KEY_MAKE);
    }

    description.setText(advert_description);
    rates.setText(advert_price);
    location.setText(advert_location);
    make.setText(advert_make);
    model.setText(advert_model);
    fuel.setText(advert_fuel);
    engine.setText(advert_engine);
    transmission.setText(advert_transmission);
    rates.setText(advert_price);

    return rootView;
}

protected class GetImages extends
        AsyncTask<CarDetailsFragment, Void, CarDetailsFragment> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected CarDetailsFragment doInBackground(
            CarDetailsFragment... params) {
        photos = getPhotos(advert_id);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CarDetailsFragment params) {
        super.onPostExecute(params);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.i("", photos.size() + "");
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), photos));
    }
}

public List<String> getPhotos(int id) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    List<String> photos_url = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("advert_id", String
            .valueOf(id)));
    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_photos);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in connection " + e.toString());
        // results.setText("Error in connection");
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    Log.i("", result);

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        // Checking for SUCCESS TAGlistener
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            JSONArray urls = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = urls.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String url = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                photos_url.add(url);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return photos_url;
}
```

And the ImageAdapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<?> listData;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context mContext;

private static final String URL = "http://safirisha.co.ke/photos/";

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<?> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
    // i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(50, 50));
    // i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(URL + listData.get(position), image);
    return null;
}

}
```

And my logcat

```
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.Gallery.setUpChild(Gallery.java:868)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:847)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:645)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:346)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:743)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-17 20:18:33.286: E/AndroidRuntime(23603):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ImageLoader class is for lazyloading the image.Where am i be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, try to return the view in the method getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
    // i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(50, 50));
    // i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(URL + listData.get(position), image);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

must not return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

protected CarDetailsFragment doInBackground(
            CarDetailsFragment... params) {
        photos = getPhotos(advert_id);
        return null;
    }
why your returning null??